# Establishing an Azure VPN connection from CLI/PowerShell

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-11, azure, azure-cli

I've installed [Azure VPN Client](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/azure-vpn-client/9NP355QT2SQB?hl=en-us&gl=us) app and configured an Azure VPN profile. It works when I manually start it via the app's UI.

How do I initiate the connection via command line, Azure CLI or PowerShell?

[`Rasdial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/ff859533(v=ws.11)) doesn't seem to work with Azure VPN Client profiles.

Comment: In Azure CLI, you might be looking for [az network vpn-connection create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/vpn-connection?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-vpn-connection-create).

Comment: @harrymc isn't it for creating a new connection?  I need to establish (activate) an existing confection.

Comment: That's why I'm asking - there are parameters that suggest that it establishes a connection to an existing VPN.

Comment: I think I've found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39638726

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (powershell)

`Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Azure VPN Client\azurevpnclient.exe" -ArgumentList "--connect" -NoNewWindow`